# Extrair objetos de um array de objetos para criar um unico objeto com todos itens

Tags: javascript

Eae gente, eu buguei aqui para resolver um probleminha. Eu tenho o seguinte array:

```
[ 
  { cachorro: 'Bob', gato: 'Mica' },
  { dono: 'Jose', dona: 'Maria },
  { outros_animais: 'sim', animais: ['cavalo', 'vaca'] }
]
```

Meu objetivo é criar um unico objeto com todos esses atributos, para o output ficar assim:

```
{
  cachorro: 'Bob',
  gato: 'Mica',
  dono: 'Jose',
  dona: 'Maria,
  outros_animais: 'sim',
  animais: 
    ['cavalo', 'vaca']
}
```

Eu acho que estou esquecendo de algo, pois não deve ser muito complicado mas enfim, buguei.

Valeu.

Edit: na real, tem objeto pra caramba e eu não sei o nome dos atributos dele. Então tem que ser algo genérico.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode tentar assim:

```js
var source = [ 
  { cachorro: 'Bob', gato: 'Mica' },
  { dono: 'Jose', dona: 'Maria' },
  { outros_animais: 'sim', animais: ['cavalo', 'vaca'] }
];

var parsed = {};

source.forEach(function (item) {
 for (var i in item) {
  parsed[i] = item[i];
 }
});

console.log(parsed);
```

**Nota:** Se um item do array conter um objeto com nome de propriedade que já foi usada, esta será sobrescrita pela última ocorrência dela no array source.

Comment: Boa meu irmão, era isso mesmo. Valeu

Comment: Nada! Só não esqueça de aceitar como resposta aceita.

Comment: Tinha que esperar um tempo minimo, tai ja x)

Answer (score 1):

Outra opção usando [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) e [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
let source = [
    { cachorro: 'Bob', gato: 'Mica' },
    { dono: 'Jose', dona: 'Maria' },
    { outros_animais: 'sim', animais: ['cavalo', 'vaca'] }
];

let result = source.reduce((acc, cur) => Object.assign(acc, cur));

console.log(result);
```